# Joda DateTime IllegalArgument exception converting a String to DateTime

Tags: android, jodatime

Im trying to convert a String to a `DateTime` object then only saving the Time part back in a `String`.

I'm getting the above exception.
How can i just exstract the time part eg H:mm from the original?

**So the original DateTime is:** `2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00`

and **i would like just the** `21:00` part.

```
Log.e(TAG, "recordItem[0] = " + recordItem[0]);

        recordItem[0] = recordItem[0].replace('[', ' ');
        recordItem[0] = recordItem[0].trim();

        recordItem[0] = recordItem[0].replace('T', ' ');



        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
        DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(recordItem[0]);

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("H:mm");
        String formattedStart = fmt.print(dt);

        Log.e(TAG, "formattedStart = " + formattedStart);

        callStartTime = formattedStart;
```

.

Console logs:

```
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/CarerDetailsFragment(6430): recordItem[0] = [2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00
05-02 16:10:25.780: D/AndroidRuntime(6430): Shutting down VM
05-02 16:10:25.780: W/dalvikvm(6430): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409ed1f8)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-05-02 21:00:00+01:00" is malformed at "+01:00"
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.CarerDetailsFragment.onListItemClick(CarerDetailsFragment.java:395)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-02 16:10:25.780: E/AndroidRuntime(6430):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[edit1]

```
05-02 16:32:10.499: E/CarerDetailsFragment(6568): recordItem[0] = 2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00
05-02 16:32:10.499: D/AndroidRuntime(6568): Shutting down VM
05-02 16:32:10.499: W/dalvikvm(6568): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409ed1f8)
05-02 16:32:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 16:32:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6568): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00" is malformed at "+01:00"
05-02 16:32:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(6568):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:866)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data pattern seems to be wrong. If your original date string is `2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00` it should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.Z` without have to trim or replace "T" char

Comment: I've put the T back in but get the following in Edit1 above. It doesn't seem to like the +0100

Comment: I think the problem is the ":" in time zone and there is a little typo in my pattern. Try this yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ and apply tranformations to have something like this 2014-05-02T21:00:00+0100

Comment: For a colon in the timezone use ZZ instead of Z

Answer (score 1):

## ISO 8601

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 standard. Both Joda-Time and java.time frameworks use this standard as their defaults when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So **no need to specify a coded parsing pattern** or formatter.

## Joda-Time

The following code creates a date-time assigned an offset-from-UTC of `+01:00`.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse( "2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00" );
```

Using a constructor has a different meaning. The following code parses the value with the embedded offset but then adjusts the results into your JVM’s current default time zone.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-05-02T21:00:00+01:00" ) );
```

To account for Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies, adjust into your desired/expected time zone rather than just an offset-from-UTC. Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in the format of `continent/region` such as `Africa/Tunis` or `Europe/Paris`. Never use the 3-4 letter codes such as `EST` or `IST` that are neither standardized nor unique.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimezone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime_Europe_Paris = dateTime.withZone( zone );
```

From that DateTime object we generate a String representation of its time-of-day value. We need a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to define this String format. Fortunately, Joda-Time already has one pre-defined for us, with just hour and minute values, accessed by calling the static method [`IsoDateTimeFormat.hourMinute()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#hourMinute--).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinute();
String output = formatter.print( dateTime_Europe_Paris );
```

Search StackOverflow for *many* more Questions and Answers with example code for Joda-Time.